# Refer specifically to key or object when using an NSDictionary in a For Loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Confusing one to explain: I'm trying to iterate a for loop through an NSMutableDictionary, looking at its "key" values, and comparing those to the "key" values of a second NSMutableDictionary. If there's a match (they're string comparisons), I want the "object" of both dictionaries to be added to a separate array.

To clarify, Dictionaries A and B both contain lists of words (object) and those words in alphabetical order (key), like so:

apple = aelpp
tomato = amoott
stack = ackst

So I need to compare "aelpp" to "amoott", but then store "apple" and "tomato".

Basic question is: when using a for loop (`for (NSString *currentWord in dictionaryA)`), how do I refer to dictionaryA's objects or keys specifically? I'll need it to compare the keys, but then store the objects if they're a match.

If anything needs more clarification, please do ask :)

Comment: On a side note, remember that NSDictionary does not have any "order" (you mentioned alphabetical order - the pairs are stored in an arbitrary order, and the order of the keys if you call `[myDict allKeys]` is undefined.)

Comment: @Aaron: From one of lukech's previous questions I assume that he means: The dictionary keys are words, and the corresponding value is the word in alphabetical order, e.g. dict["apple"] = "aelpp".

Comment: @MartinR Ahh, I think you're right.  I thought those were random letters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your "basic question": Fast enumeration of an `NSDictionary` enumerates the dictionary **keys**:

```
for (NSString *keyA in dictionaryA) {
    NSString *valueA = [dictionaryA objectForKey:keyA];
    // Now keyA : valueA is one key-value pair of dictionaryA ...
}
```

(assuming that all keys and values are strings).

Comment: You also may be interested in the NSDictionary instance method `allKeysForObject:`, which returns a new array containing the keys corresponding to all occurrences of a given object in the dictionary.  You could then add the objects from this array to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate simultaneously between Key and Values all at once, use this:

```
[dictionaryA enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * keyA,
                                                   id valueA,
                                                   BOOL *stop) {
    // You have at the same time access to keyA and valueA
}];
```